# Using VBA can I use a Proxy to webscrape using Internet Explorer?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, proxy

I have searched high and low for an answer to this.  It's something that I feel intuitively should be easily done, but such intuitions are seldom correct...

I am using VBA and Internet Explorer for web-scraping.

```
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
For Each link In URLs
    ie.Navigate, 16386
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until ie.readyState = 4

Set Doc = ie.document
```

I then use operands such as "getelementsbyclassname", etc, to extract data from the HTML document.
I don't know if this is the best method, but it works, and easily for me.
(I ave fiddled with using XML requests, but found that I often wasn't getting the right response from the website.)

As I am now getting frequently blocked as a "bot" I would like to try using random proxies from a list.
I know that with some objects this is easy by the .setproxy method, but I can't figure out how to do this using ie.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to [this article](https://ncsullivanblog.wordpress.com/2017/11/21/setting-proxy-ip-addresses-with-vba/) about setting proxy IP address with VBA. The method is to edit the registry.

First, save the following code as a **setIP.vbs** file and place it in some path you can easily reach:

```
Option Explicit
Dim valUserIn
Dim objShell, RegLocate, RegLocate1
Dim args

set args = Wscript.Arguments
valUserIn = args(0)
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
On Error Resume Next
RegLocate = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyServer"
objShell.RegWrite RegLocate,valUserIn,"REG_SZ"
RegLocate = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable"
objShell.RegWrite RegLocate,"1","REG_DWORD"
WScript.Quit
```

Second, execute this script directly from VBA and pass in the IP argument (note to change the ip address and file path to your owns):

```
Sub IPproxy()

'give the proxy server IP address
ipAddress = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

'Call the vbs script to set the new IP address
Shell "wscript the\path\of\your\file\setIP.vbs " & ipAddress, vbNormalFocus

End Sub
```

After that, when you restart IE you can see that the proxy server has been set. You could check this setting to see the effect: **Tools-> Internet Options-> Connections-> LAN Settings-> Use a proxy server for your LAN**.

Comment: I want to use Internet Explorer

Comment: @Floyd I've updated my answer. The solution is from the first link in my former answer. I also test the solution and it works in IE.